# AIR: <img> tag in Rich text editor

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, air2

Is there is there a way(may be very complicated) to display images in the text area from htmlText property in AIR2?

P.S. I know that AIR ignores img tags in HTML content due prevent possible phishing attacks.

**UPD**
Resolved: I have used Text Layout Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've answered your own question really. "AIR ignores img tags in HTML content due prevent possible phishing attacks"

From reading the bug at: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-14238

The Workaround is to use the AIR specific [HTML Control](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/HTML.html) when you need to display images. [How to use](http://blog.everythingflex.com/2008/02/25/air-html-control/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I need to use my text editor(that contains a lot lines of code) in Flex and in AIR project. Maybe there is a solution that works both Flex and AIR?

Comment: It's a bit hacky but on the initialize of the component determine if you're in Flex or AIR and then add the appropriate component to the container based on the environment. Try that out?